# C# file send, stream problem

Tags: c#, network-programming, stream, filestream, binarywriter

I have a server and a client. Server sends an executable and an input.txt to the client. Client should execute it and send output to the server but I have a problem. When I try to run executable it gives an error about argument format. After that I save input file as (make just a quick char addition and removing) executable runs succesfully after saving it as a different file altough it has the exact content.

I'm saving the file using BinaryWriter :

```
FileStream fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
BinaryWriter BW = new BinaryWriter(fs);
.......
fs.Close();
BW.Close();
```

I run executable with the parameter input.txt after closing the BinaryWriter and filestream.I think there is a problem with saving the file or maybe closing the stream but I couldnot find it yet. Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: It is pretty hard to understand what the roles/functions of client, server, executable and input.txt are here.

Comment: @Aaron error is "System.FormatException: Input String was not in a correct format". Input format is "input.txt output.txt". Starting my executable with command : x.exe input.txt output.txt but it does not work without saving input.txt as.

Answer (score 3):

A possible problem is that the last 2 lines are in the wrong order:

```
fs.Close();
BW.Close(); // tries to close the file and maybe flush some buffers
```

You should at least reverse them, but even better use `using` blocks:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
using (BinaryWriter BW = new BinaryWriter(fs))
{
    .......
}
```